# how to use apt-buildpack from cloudfoundry repo

Tags: cloud-foundry, apt, buildpack

The [apt-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack) is experimental and not yet intended for production use. I guess that's why also no documentation.

```
Creating container          
Successfully created container                           
Downloading app package...  
Downloaded app package (862.7K)                          
Warning: this buildpack can only be run as a supply buildpack, it can not be run alone                             
Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 1                                                
Destroying container        
Exit status 223             
Stopping instance abdfc8d0-699e-4834-9f2d-2b8aec218423   
Successfully destroyed container
```

Can you give me example how to push `cf-env` sample app and install for example [rtorrent](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rtorrent) and/or [openvpn](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openvpn). Is it possible to install [gnome](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome) for testing purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as usage goes it's pretty simple, you just need to include an `apt.yml` in the root directory of your app.  That should contain among other things, the list of packages to install.

Ex:

```
---
packages:
- ascii
- libxml
- https://example.com/exciting.deb
```

The buildpack supports installing package names, deb files, custom APT repositories, and even PPAs.

Please see the [README](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack/tree/develop#buildpack-user-documentation) for further instructions.

This message:

> Warning: this buildpack can only be run as a supply buildpack, it can not be run alone

Is telling you that the Apt buildpack only functions to supply binaries.  It doesn't actually know how to run your app or any application.  For more on the supply script, check out the [docs here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/understand-buildpacks.html#supply-script).

The trick to making it work is that you need to use multi buildpack support.  Instructions for doing that can be found [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html).  This should work with most apps, but there's a simple example [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack/tree/develop/fixtures/simple).

Once your app stages & starts, you can confirm that your packages were installed by running `cf ssh apt-test -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"`.  Anything that was installed should be on the path, but if you want to see where things are installed it'll be under the `/home/vcap/deps/<buildpack-number>/`.

That should be about it.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46740305/7661683) is correct and provides links to documentation, but here I'd like to give an example for a WAR-packaged Spring Boot Java application using Maven.

1. In your `manifest.yml` the `buildpacks` section should look like this:

```
    buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack.git
      - java_buildpack
```

Note that `apt-buildpack`: a) uses git repository since it is experimental b) is first in the buildpacks list.

2. In my `manifest.yml` path to application artifact looks like this:

```
path: ./target/ROOT.war
```

So the `apt.yml` could be added to the WAR file during application build time. For `apt.yml` being in the folder one level above `src` adding a build plugin into `pom.xml` should work:

```
...
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-apt.yml</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <copy file="${project.build.directory}/../apt.yml" tofile="${project.build.directory}/ROOT/apt.yml" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
...
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

where `ROOT` is the directory of future `ROOT.WAR` file. This command will copy `apt.yml` file to the folder from which the resulting WAR file will be generated.

3. The `apt.yml` could look like this:

```
---
packages:
  - libnss3
  - libnspr4
  - libatk1.0-0
  - libatk-bridge2.0-0
  - libcups2
  - libxkbcommon0
  - libatspi2.0-0
  - libxcomposite1
  - libxdamage1
  - libxrandr2
  - libgbm1
  - libasound2
```

In this example it is placed in the application's repository root directory, same as `pom.xml` and `manifest.yml`.

4. run `cf push -f manifest.yml` as usual, you should see that apt packages are being installed before the Java buildpack kicks in:

```
Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading java_buildpack...
   Downloaded java_buildpack
   Cell ac23eeb2-9362-4216-b862-b0123510ab96 creating container for instance ea262703-b1b1-4298-82ec-df56000956fd
   Security group rules were updated
   Cell ac23eeb2-9362-4216-b862-b0123510ab96 successfully created container for instance ea262703-b1b1-4298-82ec-df56000956fd
   Downloading app package...
   Downloading build artifacts cache...
   Downloaded build artifacts cache (138B)
   Downloaded app package (276.3M)
   -----> Download go 1.19
   -----> Running go build supply
   /tmp/buildpackdownloads/3f6188191ee386ccd86c13b8a9cd4b0d ~
   ~
   -----> Apt Buildpack version 0.3.0
   -----> Updating apt cache
   -----> Downloading apt packages
   Reading package lists...
   Building dependency tree...
   The following additional packages will be installed:
   alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core dbus dbus-user-session
   dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service gsettings-desktop-schemas
   libasound2-data libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data
   libavahi-common3 libdconf1 libpam-systemd libwayland-server0 libxi6 libxtst6
   session-migration
   Suggested packages:
   libasound2-plugins alsa-utils cups-common
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
   alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core dbus dbus-user-session
   dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service gsettings-desktop-schemas libasound2
   libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
   libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libdconf1
   libgbm1 libnspr4 libnss3 libpam-systemd libwayland-server0 libxcomposite1
   libxdamage1 libxi6 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxtst6 session-migration
   0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
   Need to get 3,236 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 11.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 dbus amd64 1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1 [158 kB]
   Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 [203 kB]
   Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 alsa-topology-conf all 1.2.5.1-2 [15.5 kB]
   Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasound2-data all 1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1 [19.1 kB]
   Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasound2 amd64 1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1 [390 kB]
   Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 alsa-ucm-conf all 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.7 [41.8 kB]
   Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxi6 amd64 2:1.8-1build1 [32.6 kB]
   Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libatspi2.0-0 amd64 2.44.0-3 [80.9 kB]
   Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxtst6 amd64 2:1.2.3-1build4 [13.4 kB]
   Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 dbus-user-session amd64 1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1 [9,442 B]
   Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libdconf1 amd64 0.40.0-3 [40.5 kB]
   Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 dconf-service amd64 0.40.0-3 [28.5 kB]
   Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 dconf-gsettings-backend amd64 0.40.0-3 [22.8 kB]
   Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 session-migration amd64 0.3.6 [9,774 B]
   Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 gsettings-desktop-schemas all 42.0-1ubuntu1 [31.1 kB]
   Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 at-spi2-core amd64 2.44.0-3 [54.4 kB]
   Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libatk1.0-data all 2.36.0-3build1 [2,824 B]
   Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libatk1.0-0 amd64 2.36.0-3build1 [51.9 kB]
   Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libatk-bridge2.0-0 amd64 2.38.0-3 [66.6 kB]
   Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common-data amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5.1 [23.5 kB]
   Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common3 amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5.1 [23.7 kB]
   Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libavahi-client3 amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5.1 [28.0 kB]
   Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.4 [264 kB]
   Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libwayland-server0 amd64 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 [34.3 kB]
   Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 [33.1 kB]
   Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libnspr4 amd64 2:4.32-3build1 [119 kB]
   Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.2 [1,280 kB]
   Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxcomposite1 amd64 1:0.4.5-1build2 [7,192 B]
   Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxdamage1 amd64 1:1.1.5-2build2 [7,154 B]
   Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxkbcommon0 amd64 1.4.0-1 [125 kB]
   Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libxrandr2 amd64 2:1.5.2-1build1 [20.4 kB]
   Fetched 3,236 kB in 1s (2,393 kB/s)
   Download complete and in download only mode

   -----> Installing apt packages






   
























   -----> Java Buildpack v4.59.0 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#cb826d45
   -----> Downloading Jvmkill Agent 1.17.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/jvmkill/jammy/x86_64/jvmkill-1.17.0-RELEASE.so (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Sap Machine JRE 11.0.19_0.0.b0 from https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases/download/sapmachine-11.0.19/sapmachine-jre-11.0.19_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz (found in cache)
   Expanding Sap Machine JRE to .java-buildpack/sap_machine_jre (0.9s)
   JVM DNS caching disabled in lieu of BOSH DNS caching
   -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 3.13.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/memory-calculator/jammy/x86_64/memory-calculator-3.13.0-RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
   Loaded Classes: 41780, Threads: 250
   -----> Multiple Buildpacks detected
   apt contributed to: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $PATH
   -----> Downloading Client Certificate Mapper 1.11.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/client-certificate-mapper/client-certificate-mapper-1.11.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Container Customizer 2.6.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/container-customizer/container-customizer-2.6.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Container Security Provider 1.20.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/container-security-provider/container-security-provider-1.20.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Instance 9.0.75 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat/tomcat-9.0.75.tar.gz (found in cache)
   Expanding Tomcat Instance to .java-buildpack/tomcat (0.1s)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Access Logging Support 3.4.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-access-logging-support/tomcat-access-logging-support-3.4.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Lifecycle Support 3.4.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-lifecycle-support/tomcat-lifecycle-support-3.4.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Logging Support 3.4.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-logging-support/tomcat-logging-support-3.4.0-RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   Exit status 0
   Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   Uploading droplet...
   Uploading build artifacts cache...
   Uploaded build artifacts cache (29.9M)
```