# How can I install drivers for MSSQL in CloudFoundry?

Tags: sql-server, django, cloud-foundry

I am trying to host Django application on CloudFoundry. The application uses MSSQL in backend. After the application's state changes to "started", When I browse the URL I get ERROR:

Exception Value:

> `('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

I have followed a Solution for this error here:
[Pivotal/Django settings for user provided MSSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087045/pivotal-django-settings-for-user-provided-mssql-database)

Still not able to resolve this. The path is not getting set correctly for the driver.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: It's missing the MSSQL ODBC driver. It seems to be looking for an older version. If you're following the instructions from the SO post you linked, then you should be using Driver 17. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: yes that helped, Worked with Driver 17, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivotal/Django settings for user provided MSSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087045/pivotal-django-settings-for-user-provided-mssql-database)