# Getting pyodbc to connect in Cloud Foundry

Tags: python, pyodbc, cloud-foundry

I am trying to get a python script to deploy to Cloud Foundry which uses pyobdc to connect to sql server and execute commands. My pyobdc connection statement looks like so:

```
warehouse_connection = pyodbc.connect(f'Driver={DRIVER}'
                                          f';Server={SERVER}'
                                          f';Database={DATABASE}'
                                          f';UID={USERNAME}'
                                          f';PWD={PASSWORD}'
                                          ';Trusted_Connection=no')
warehouse_cursor = warehouse_connection.cursor()
```

The driver I am using is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and I have the odbcinst.ini file which looks like so:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

My script works fine on my local machine so I know the access account info is up to date and I have other scripts that use that driver which work fine, but when I try to deploy to Cloud Foundry I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout 
expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I tried changing the trusted connection variable, made sure my apt/environment was up to date, I am not sure what I am missing. Is there in issue with pyodbc in Cloud Foundry or am I getting something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have basic network connectivity from your app running on CF to your SQL Server? My suggestion would be to stabilize the app, so push up something just to get it running. Then `cf ssh` into your app container and see if you can at least `nc -v <server> <port>` and make a TCP connection to your server.

Comment: Also, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58105873/1585136 is primarily for PHP + MSSQL + ODBC, but you can follow the part about using the apt-buildpack and installing `mssql-tools`. You can then use `sqlcmd` from the cli after you `cf ssh` into the app. That's another way you can validate that you can connect from inside the container, which separates the problem from ODBC setup & connectivity versus something in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes back an looks at this, it turns out all we needed to do was open up firewall access from that cloud foundry space and then it worked. Posted this a while ago and realized I should probably answer it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, we are running into a similar issue. This might help.