# Install libc6-dev, libgdiplus and libx11-dev using manifest.yml file on Cloud foundry

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy an asp.net core 3.1 API on cloud foundry. I don't have admin rights, i just have developer rights. Is there a way to specify the URL of these libraries (libc6-dev, libgdiplus and libx11-dev) (maybe git or some official repository) so that i can execute the manifest.yml file during deployment and install these dependencies? Also to mention, i cannot turn on support for docker file on cloud foundry, as i get a message (insufficient rights)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you give the apt-buildpack a try. You can give it additional Ubuntu package names, and it will install those for you.

You do that through an apt.yml file. Check out [this post for instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736992/how-to-use-apt-buildpack-from-cloudfoundry-repo/46740305#46740305).

It's important to understand that the apt-buildpack will install these packages into a non-standard location. Since it also runs as a non-root user, it cannot install them into standard locations.

To work around this limitation, it sets variables like `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the locations where it has installed items. Most build tools will pick up these env variables and be able to locate what you install.

It's not perfect though, and some tools require additional env variables to be set. If you still get errors when building, look at your build tools and check if there are ways you can point to where apt-buildpack is installing stuff. The path it writes to can vary based on your buildpack order, but if you print out `$PATH` you can see the location. It's often `/home/vcap/deps/0/...` but the index can change based on your buildpack order.